# Find the points on the given curve where the tangent line is horizontal or vertical.

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Please help! I don't know how else to do this question. Thank you!!

[image: 10]

Comment: What before  else  so far done ?

Answer (score 1):

You are given $r$ as a function of $\theta$,i.e., $r=f(\theta)$, so you rewrite the usual identities: $$x = rcos(\theta)$$ $$y=rsin(\theta)$$

As: $$x=f(\theta)cos(\theta)$$ $$y=f(\theta)sin(\theta)$$

Then, it is a simple exercise to show that:$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}} = \frac{f'(\theta)sin(\theta)+f(\theta)cos(\theta)}{f'(\theta)cos(\theta)-f(\theta)sin(\theta)}$$

Finally, since $f'(\theta)=\frac{d}{d\theta}e^{\theta}=e^{\theta}=f(\theta)$ this simplifies to:$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{sin(\theta)+cos(\theta)}{cos(\theta)-sin(\theta)}$$

So, when is this final equation equal to $0$? When is it indeterminate? And what does this imply about the slope of the tangent line?